Prove that exponentiation is continuous
This is from Tao's Analysis textbook. Let $>0$ be a positive real number. Then the function $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ defined $():=^$ is continuous. It is hinted that we utilize the given theorems/lemmas

What I have :
We show continuity for arbitrary $c$ in $\Bbb{R}$. Pick some $\epsilon > 0$. By Lemma 6.5.3 $(a>0)$, $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} a^{1/n} = 1$$. $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} a^{c}= a^{c} $$ as it's a constant sequence and convergent (shown in an earlier question). Since they are both convergent, we use algebra of limits and $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} a^{{1/n} +    c} = a^{c}$$ We can also similarly show
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} a^{c-\frac{1}{n}} = a^{c}$$
c is a real number, so some sequence of reals must converge to c. For all such sequences $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = c$$
As the squeeze theorem so far only works for sequences not limits, I probably need to work with sequences and rely on the result that a function being converging to a limit at an adherent point in a set is the same as (for every sequence $(b_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ which consists entirely of elements of the set and converges to $x_0$, the sequence $(f(b_n))_{n=0}^\infty$ converges to $L$.
). I want to show that the sequence of $a^{b_n}$ is bounded above by the first and below by the second or something to that effect, so I can use the squeeze theorem, but I don't think that works.

I think we're restricted to the part (e) of 5.6.9 (shown in the image link). If $( x > 1 )$ , then $( x^q > x^r )$ if and only if  $( q > r )$ . If $( x < 1 )$ , then $( x^q > x^r )$ if and only if $( q < r )$.

I'm really sorry for not getting it but wouldn't we need to show that for any arbitrary convergent sequence $b_n$,  $a^{b_n}$  converges to $a^c$.  I thought we needed some version of $a^{c - \frac{1}{n}} ≤ a^{b_n} ≤ a^{c + \frac{1}{n}}$

You have it by Proposition 6.7.3 and lemma 5.6.9.e, since wlog $c-\frac1n\le b_n\le c+\frac1n$.
